# setenv path precedence

Tags: environment-variables

I'v got to include the path of a same software but two different version installed in two different location, since I have no edit permission of these file and there are some other softwares in these different location so I need to include both of the directories.

The first dir `$HOME` contains lots of softwares, while the second dir `/grid/common/` contains fewer but all newer versions. So I want the second folder to precedes the first folder when defining the path environment variable.

In my script:

```
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH $HOME/lib:/grid/common/lib
```

Does `/grid/common/` precede `$HOME` or `$HOME` precede `/grid/common/` in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter: `$HOME/lib` precedes (overrides) `/grid/common/lib`.  By convention, environment variables which give a list of colon-separated directory paths are from *left-to-right*.

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) lists several "path" variables, all are processed left-to-right, including `CDPATH`, `NLSPATH`, `PATH`.  Oddly it does not mention this one (which is more often used than several of the variables listed).

Usually the documentation does not say left-to-right, but just says "order", assuming the reader's cultural bias fills in the rest of the details:

- [Program Library HOWTO: 3.3.1. LD_LIBRARY_PATH](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html)
- [4.3.2 LD_LIBRARY_PATH Environment Variable](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5262/aeude/index.html)
- [In which order does the linker process the library directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865594/in-which-order-does-the-linker-process-the-library-directories)

Comment: `/grib/common/lib` is the latter one